# Why is my mongoose query so slow? (~30 seconds)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a route that expects the id of a user to return an array of offers the user has written on the app. If the user has written just a few offers the query returns fairly fast however once I get to about 10 offers the query becomes absurdly slow.

I've looked into indexing but not sure how to go about that.

This is the route:

```
 router.get('/offers', passport_admin.authenticate('admin-rule', { 
 session: false }), (req, res) => {
 const userId = req.query.id
 Offer.find({user: userId})
     .then(offers => {
     if(offers){
       if(offers.length > 0){
        res.json(offers)
        } else {
         res.json({msg: 'This user has not made any offers yet.'})
        }

        } else {
      res.status(400).json({msg: 'User not found'})
        }

      })
   });
```

Here's one of the 12 offer objects I'm expecting back for this particular user. I know it's quite large but still...:

```
  [ { _id: 5cad4493fe8ff00017f0d9ab,
    user: 5cad438cfe8ff00017f0d9aa,
    propertyAddress: '56585 South SW 368 ST& SW 214 AV Groves #6A2',
     propertyDetails:
     { privateRemarks:
    'This property is a trial property to test the SimplyRETS. Private agent remarks will be included in this field for use in the SimplyRETS REST API. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
   showingContactName: null,
   property: [Object],
   mlsId: 1005160,
   showingContactPhone: null,
   terms:
    'Submit,Cash,Cash To Existing Loan,Cash To New Loan,Assumable,Exchange,Owner May Carry,Owner Will Carry,Trade',
   showingInstructions:
    'The showing instructions for this trial property are brought to you by the SimplyRETS team. This field will include any showing remarks for the given listing in your RETS feed. Enjoy!',
   office: [Object],
   leaseTerm: null,
   disclaimer:
    'This information is believed to be accurate, but without warranty.',
   address: [Object],
   agreement: 'Exclusive Agency',
   listDate: '1995-01-05T21:20:35.957061Z',
   agent: [Object],
   modified: '2003-05-30T17:37:32.270926Z',
   school: [Object],
   photos: [Array],
   listPrice: 21445988,
   listingId: '51337707',
   mls: [Object],
   geo: [Object],
   tax: [Object],
   coAgent: [Object],
   sales: [Object],
   leaseType: 'Modified Gross',
   virtualTourUrl: null,
   remarks:
    'This property is a trial property to test the SimplyRETS. This field will include remarks or descriptions from your RETS feed intended for public view. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
   association: [Object],
   favorite: false },
offerDetails:
 { fullNameErr: '',
   emailErr: '',
   phoneErr: '',
   downpaymentErr: '',
   preApprovalErr: '',
   homeInspectionErr: '',
   appraisalErr: '',
   loanErr: '',
   escrowErr: '',
   msg: '',
   fullName: 'Ryan Brennan',
   cobuyerName: 'Ryan Brennan',
   email: 'Ryansbrennan444@gmail.com',
   phone: '215.760.4950',
   cobuyerEmail: 'eatshit@gmail.com',
   priceErr: '',
   price: '$21,000,000',
   mortgage: true,
   downpayment: '$1,000,000',
   preApproval: [Object],
   homeInspectionDays: '45',
   appraisalDays: '10',
   loanDays: '45',
   escrowDays: '10',
   proofOfFunds: [Object],
   proofOfFundsErr: '' },
date: 2019-04-10T01:19:15.739Z,
__v: 0 } ]
```

Here's my offer model:

```
 const OfferSchema = new Schema({

  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
 },
    propertyAddress: {
    type: String,
    required: true
 },
    propertyDetails: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
 },
    offerDetails: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
 },
    date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
 }
});
```

I expect for this query to return in less then 30 seconds.

Comment: Try fetching only required properties or fields

Comment: Check: 1. time taken by express to get back mongo result,maybe network delay. 2. Run the find query by connecting through some ide like robo 3t and see the stats

Comment: Try to run the query on mongo and analyze it. It might be issue with index or express

Comment: Please try to re-index only required and minimal fields only on your existing collection. Also check the amount of time taken by passport middleware and controller where you have written find query. And update the time taken in your question. You can use `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` to print the time.

Comment: Turns out that reshaping the data to return objects with only 3 of the properties from the large object increased latency to 4371.439ms. The current setup clocks at 3218.344ms. This time is for when the route receives the request until mongoose is done fullfilling the transaction.

Comment: take a look at `https://crowdfire.engineering/why-orm-shouldnt-be-your-best-bet-887e3e4ded2a`

Answer (score 0):

> I've looked into indexing but not sure how to go about that.

If you don't have an index, this is inevitably going to be slow. A good start would be creating an index for `user` because that's what you're querying on (`Offer.find({user: userId})`). If you're connected to mongo, something like `db.Offer.createIndex({user: 1})` should be a good start.

[This page in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/) is a good starting point for learning about indexes.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. So I created an index at mlab for user (as you suggested) within the Offer collection but didn't see a decrease in latency. I've tested for with and without index and the time for the transaction to fullfill is around 11,000ms.

Comment: Mlab has a logs tab that should log every slow query over 100ms (and a lot of other stuff). There will be details there about why this is slow. (they also have a performance recommendations section that's good at identifying problems, and sometimes has good index suggestions)